# best way to handle large js files in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

i am building a stats pack for one of the applications i have built and i would like to have 8 graphs on the page showing different info. the problem is- whats the best way iterate through my data in a js file? (or add base_url() into style sheets?

i keep my js in root /scripts

currently i have 8 graphs with for my google charts-

```
 function drawtwitterChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'x');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Twitter');

    <?foreach($twitter_results->result_array() as $twitter_result){?>
        data.addRow(["<?=$twitter_result['hour']?>", <?=goAssocArrayNumeric($twitter_result,0)?>]);
    <?}?>
      // Set chart options
      var options = {'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
                     'width':300,
                     'height':250};
      new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('twitter_chart_div')).
      draw(data, {curveType: "function",
                  width: 400, height: 320,
                  vAxis: {maxValue: 10}}
          );
    }
```

all this is in the header of my page, i would like to remove this and place it into js files? need to still iterate through the data- wondering how others do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to approach this.

The simplest would be to create a controller for your dynamically generated JS. Before calling the view that outputs the JS, set the response header:

```
$this->output->set_header('Content-type: text/javascript');
```

If you have lots of JS files, you can take it even further by making all of your JS links call this controller. You can customize the links to request all of your JS files in a single call, and the controller can combine them and serve them as a single file. You can include version info in the request to make sure you get the correct version and prevent JS from being cached when you need to update it.

Taking it even further, the controller can cache the combined files for a given version so you don't have to process it each time it is requested. If you have JS files that need dynamic content, you can tier your JS so that static JS files are combined and cached, then the dynamic JS files are generated each time, combined with the cached static, and then served.